# How to pass a list (returned in a VB.net function) in VBScript?

Tags: vb.net, list, vbscript, vb.net-2010

I have a system function in VB.net that return a list of Strings (I've debugged this function).
And right now I need to call that system function in VBScript. How can I get that list of strings?

[image]

VB.net system function

```
Public Function someList As List(Of String)
    Return List
End Function
```

VBScript:

```
Dim results
Set results = System.someList

For Each result In results
    wscript.echo result
Next
```

Comment: Check out this link [How to call a .NET DLL from a vb script](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79314/How-to-call-a-NET-DLL-from-a-VBScript)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have some system functions that need to be called by the vbscript file. And all the others functions can be called successful. Only this function returns a List that couldn't be called. So I think the return type of this function might cause the problem. I wonder can I still use List as the return type? Or I need to change the return type to ArrayList? Or do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: VBScript cannot use .Net APIs unless the .Net class exposes a COM interface (like `ArrayList` or `StringBuilder`).

Comment: Also, all the other functions are called by the function name. I use something like this: wscript.echo System.FunctionName. And when I run the file it gives me the correct value in the popup window

Comment: Actually, the other system function is the existing functions. I'm adding this new function to return a list.

Comment: `WScript` is an intrinsic object provided by the runtime environment (more specifically by the interpreters `wscript.exe` and `cscript.exe`). The same does not apply to the .Net `System` namespace.

Comment: Code references C# but might be useful - [How to correctly marshal VB-Script arrays to and from a COM component written in C#](//stackoverflow.com/q/5079200)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that VBScript doesn't understand Generic classes (or is it COM that is the problem?), so you'll have to convert your list to something non-generic such as `ArrayList`.

I had the same problem when trying to use my C# library from VBScript and I wrote a simple conversion function (in C#) to overcome this problem:

```
    public ArrayList toArrayList(IEnumerable collection)
    {
        var arrayList = new ArrayList();
        foreach (object element in collection)
        {
            arrayList.Add(element);
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
```

Some more helper functions I needed to get things working can be found here: [ScriptingInteropHelper](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/blob/master/EAAddinFramework/Utilities/ScriptingInteropHelper.cs)